# How do I show hours instead of days for an interval in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, formatting, intervals, days, hour

One of my queries is returning the below `interval`. Istead of showing `6 days`, I would like to show 6 x 24 + 19 hours. I would rather not convert to epoch using the `extract (epoch from ...)` operator. Is there a quick an easy way to do it?

```
 usage_minus_lost_data_gaps_and_battery_charge 
-----------------------------------------------
 6 days 19:18:21
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could probably help:

```
# select to_char('6 days 19:18:21'::interval, 'DD x 24 + HH24 hours');
      to_char       
--------------------
 06 x 24 + 19 hours
(1 row)
```

Comment: Szymon, thanks. How about if I wanted to show the entire interval as the total number of hours? eg. 163.305833 hours (since 6 days 19 hours 18 minutes 21 seconds = 163.305833 hours)

Comment: select extract('epoch' from '6 days 19:18:21'::interval) / 3600;